# F#: Checking whether a URL returns HTTP Error 404

Tags: web, f#

I am new to programming and F# is my first language. I am currently still very unfamiliar with .NET APIs.

I want to write a function that, given a specific URL, will return TRUE if the HTTP status code is 200, and will return FALSE if it is 404.

Here is the code I have written:

```
open System.Net

let checkIfUrlIsValid (url: string) =
    try
        let webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
        let webRequest.Method = "HEAD"
        use webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse()
        webResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
    with
        :? System.Net.WebException -> false
```

However, I get the following error message:

> The namespace or module 'HttpWebRequest' is not defined

What went wrong? What changes should I make?

Comment: BTW: I am very impressed - if this is your first language and you are unfamiliar with .NET you are doing great! - I'm sure you will be out-coding us all in no time ;)

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement, Carsten. I owe my progress to helpful and patient people like you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first there is a slight problem with the `=` in there - you have to use `<-` without `let` to mutate values:

```
open System.Net

let checkIfUrlIsValid (url: string) =
    try
        let webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
        webRequest.Method <- "HEAD"
        use webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse()
        // ...
    with
        :? System.Net.WebException -> false
```

but then the next problem is, that there is no `StatusCode` on `WebResponse` and you have to cast it explicitly (to `HttpWebResponse`), so this should finaly work:

```
open System.Net

let checkIfUrlIsValid (url: string) =
    try
        let webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
        webRequest.Method <- "HEAD"
        use webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse() :?> HttpWebResponse
        webResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
    with
        :? System.Net.WebException -> false
```

Here is a small test-run ;)

```
> checkIfUrlIsValid "http://stackoverflow.com";;
val it : bool = true
> checkIfUrlIsValid "http://stackoverflox.com";;
val it : bool = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this:

```
open System.Net

let checkIfUrlIsValid (url: string) =
   try
      let mutable  webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
      webRequest.Method <- "HEAD"
      use webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse() :?> HttpWebResponse
      webResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
   with
      :? System.Net.WebException -> false
```